# Cucumber test for AJAX call testing data has been saved

Tags: cucumber, capybara, race-condition

I have a web page which makes an AJAX call to update data in the database.  I want to write a cucumber test to enter the data on the page, triggering the AJAX call, and then verify that the data was saved in the database.

```
When I fill in selectized with "BP"
And  I enter selectized
And  Bug "222222" should have tag "BP"
```

However, because AJAX is asynchronous, cucumber is testing that the bug has a tag *before* the controller has finished creating the data.

How can I have the test wait until the AJAX call is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for an AJAX using selenium `JavascriptExecutor`

example:

```
public boolean isAjaxDone() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Object result = js.executeScript("return document.readyState");
    return result.equals("complete");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for whatever visual change on the page indicates the data has been saved/ajax has completed before checking the database. Sometimes that's a a text message

```
expect(page).to have_text('Bug Updated!')
```

sometimes it's a spinner disappearing

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector('.spinner')
```

etc.  Something like that should probably be the last line of your `I enter selectized` step.

Note: This issue is one of the main reasons doing direct DB checks in feature tests is generally considered a bad code smell (makes sense in a request spec, etc), and you really should just be checking the information shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could poll for the expected result for a certain time and only fail if it hasn't gotten the expected result within that specified timeframe.